# How to extract the colnames which the largest three numbers in every row correspond to in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like this :

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10)
colnames(x) <- combn(letters[1:8], 2, FUN = paste0, collapse = '')[seq_len(ncol(x))]
```

I want to extract the colnames which the largest three numbers in every row correspond to. I try to use following code to solve this problem:

```
apply(x,1,function(x) order(x,decreasing=T)[1:3])
```

or

```
apply(x,1,function(x) x[order(x,decreasing=T)[1:3]])
```

But I only extract the values or the column numbers, not colnames.Futher, if I want values and colnames both in a cell in a 3×10 matrix, and every cell like this: (value, its colname), how should I improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call for values, not names, in your apply-call.

Use

```
t(apply(x,1,function(x) names(x[order(x, decreasing = T)])[1:3]))
```

to get

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "ac" "ae" "bc"
 [2,] "ah" "ae" "bd"
 [3,] "ab" "ad" "ah"
 [4,] "ah" "ae" "ag"
 [5,] "bc" "ac" "ab"
 [6,] "ad" "be" "ah"
 [7,] "ag" "be" "ah"
 [8,] "be" "bd" "ag"
 [9,] "ae" "ad" "bc"
[10,] "ac" "ad" "bc"
```

To combine the values and colnames, do this:

```
mymatrix <- t(matrix(paste(apply(x,1,function(x) x[order(x,decreasing=T)[1:3]]), 
                      apply(x,1,function(x) names(x[order(x, decreasing = T)])[1:3]),
                      sep = ", "), nrow = 3))
```

Output:

```
     [,1]                    [,2]                    [,3]                   
 [1,] "1.59913311795783, ac"  "0.885534156178676, ae" "0.875246820694047, bc"
 [2,] "1.88262373384617, ah"  "0.872567862286068, ae" "0.660631089010629, bd"
 [3,] "1.49244514568881, ab"  "1.35311293758955, ad"  "0.394056724464136, ah"
 [4,] "2.32470081848151, ah"  "1.50673571308499, ae"  "0.447576219573032, ag"
 [5,] "1.51100753431057, bc"  "0.977989261628962, ac" "0.943834483720892, ab"
 [6,] "1.73431308924992, ad"  "1.19278829328726, be"  "0.718634846412602, ah"
 [7,] "0.930041809046426, ag" "0.800971669579496, be" "0.35523503674387, ah" 
 [8,] "0.759183586558264, be" "0.284400004143193, bd" "0.16139357971149, ag" 
 [9,] "1.45860700391869, ae"  "0.767188128292325, ad" "0.760496361266797, bc"
[10,] "1.89419796606409, ac"  "1.1554236572704, ad"   "0.850762486867097, bc"
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the column numbers corresponding to the three highest values for each row

```
> y <- t(apply(x, 1, order, decreasing=TRUE)[1:3,])
```

Then build an array that can be used as an index on `x` to extract the values

```
> i <- cbind(1:nrow(x), c(y))
```

Now get the column names and corresponding values

```
> cnames <- replace(y, TRUE, colnames(x)[i[,2]])
> values <- replace(y, TRUE, x[i])
```

Finally combine the two

```
> replace(y, TRUE, sprintf('(% .3f,%s)', c(values), c(cnames)))
      [,1]          [,2]          [,3]         
 [1,] "( 1.633,ac)" "( 1.277,ad)" "( 0.609,bc)"
 [2,] "( 0.660,bd)" "( 0.269,be)" "( 0.184,ab)"
 [3,] "( 0.970,ae)" "( 0.698,ag)" "( 0.204,ac)"
 [4,] "( 1.014,ac)" "( 0.158,ad)" "( 0.090,af)"
 [5,] "( 1.481,ae)" "( 0.975,ad)" "( 0.035,ag)"
 [6,] "( 2.007,ag)" "( 0.823,bd)" "( 0.699,be)"
 [7,] "( 2.019,ag)" "( 1.535,be)" "( 1.273,bd)"
 [8,] "( 1.972,ah)" "( 1.320,ac)" "( 0.878,be)"
 [9,] "( 2.261,ae)" "( 0.972,af)" "( 0.422,bc)"
[10,] "( 1.434,ad)" "( 0.979,af)" "( 0.527,bd)"
```